# performaction ACTION_SET_SELECTION not working properly

Tags: android, accessibility, android-seekbar

I am new at working with the accessibility library of android i have a lot of troubles. But there is one i think is not my fault:
I want to use the accessibilitynodeinfo to start a seekbar from the middle:

```
if(mychildinfo.getClassName().toString().contains("SeekBar")){              
         Bundle b = new Bundle();
         b.putInt(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ARGUMENT_SELECTION_START_INT, 49);
         b.putInt(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ARGUMENT_SELECTION_END_INT, 50);
         mychildinfo.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SET_SELECTION,b);
}
```

but it doesn't work and i don't get any feedback of something to be wrong in my code?
Can anybody help me, please?

I use android 4.4.2 in Nexus 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use AccessibilityNodeInfo.performAction() to specify seek bar position. The ACTION_SET_SELECTION action is only implemented in TextView.

Comment: It is somehow strange because i see the SET SELECTION ACTION as a return value in the getActions() function. But thanks a lot! Do you know if there is any way to specify the seek bar position using the Accessibility Library?

Comment: You can move it forward and back in 20% increments using ACTION_SCROLL_FORWARD and ACTION_SCROLL_BACKWARD, but you can't set a specific value.